# C optimization of extern global variables

Tags: c, optimization

In case I have a C file that uses an `extern` declared variable
and in the code the variable is modified and then an external function is called.

will the *compiler optimization* take into account the possibility that the variable can be touched by the function? so it won't change the C code order and make sure the variable is set in memory before the function is called?

Comment: Yes, of course. Anything else would be scary.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you are presuming that he's not running on bare metal and modifying the variable in an interrupt handler or something... where `volatile` would / could help.

Comment: What is this C/C++ from your header? There is C and there is C++. But no C/C++.

Comment: @Gerhardh - Sure there is. It's what you get when you shoot yourself in foot by writing C code and building it with a C++ compiler. That way, you can avoid the best features of *both* languages :P

Comment: @StoryTeller ah, I see. I always thought, the official technical word for this would simply be _crap_ ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh - Well if you want to be pedantic about it :P

Answer (score 4):

You need to be careful of a number of things... but in a basic C application with a single thread, yes... this *should* be fine.

---

If, however you are (non-exhaustive):

- Using multiple threads
- Using shared memory between a number of processes
- Running on a low-level system (e.g: AVR / STM32) and handling the variable in the an interrupt handler **and** under `main()`
- Handling the variable in a signal handler and under `main()`
- Reading memory / registers that are modified by hardware / DMA

Then you'll need to be careful.

The `volatile` keyword can be useful - it will inform the compiler that "*this variable may change while you're not looking*".

Even with the `volatile` keyword though, you may run into the [Read-Modify-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-modify-write) problem...

Knowing about the Read-Modify-Write problem is half the fight... the other half is mitigating it, which can be achieved by a number of optiosn such as using a technique called [Mutual Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) / Critical Sections, or if appropriate by copying the data into a local variable before you operate on the value.